# Slow image loading react web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Using create-react-app to develop a local web app. The initial loading of the apps' images are pretty slow, considering they are being loading locally.

After the initial launch the images are cached. So loading times are fine from there.

Is there a possibility of serving the images from the public folder? just wondering if using web pack image conversion is causing the images to be loaded slower.

Any suggestions would be be awesome!

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: Just a small thought on this one. Did you try to run a build and serve it from a configured web-server (XAMPP etc.)?

Comment: Use require() API from node inside image src tag. ```<img src={require("path")}/> ``` . Also you can put images in public folder and excess it ```<img src={`${window.location.host}/images/yourfile`}/> ```

Comment: @mohanpd thanks for your suggestion. I haven't seen a noticable decrease in loading time. I've added it to html5 preload and serviceWorker for caching.